# while building react-native app using expo build:android i am getting MaxListenersExceededWarning error

Tags: react-native, expo

MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 
11 change listeners added to [HasteMap]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by adding

```js
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 25
```

to index.js file

Comment: I am using expo, I don't have an index file.  Are you talking about main page App.js.

Comment: Hmm.. well.. give it a try on the App.js. If it doesn't work, eject your project from expo and then you'll see the index.js file